# Challenges with responsive menu on media screen

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am struggling to find what's wrong with [the menu of my blog](http://www.dontplayahate.com) on media screen. With 50% of visits on mobile, this is a big concern.  I have been reading a lot of posts but I cannot fix the problem by myself.

The problem is essentially that you cannot click on any of the categories while on media screen, so the menu remains essentially useless.

The menu CSS looks like this, basically the behaviour should be similar to a flyout menu where links appear in block format. Each internal dropdown menu can still be toggled which grants access to sub-nav elements without sacrificing screen space.

```csh
#nav
{   
list-style-type: none;
height: 60px; 
width: 1000px;
float:left;
}
#nav > a
{
    display: none;
}

#nav li
{
position: relative;
float: left; 
list-style: none;
left: 0;
position: relative;
z-index:1;
}

/* first level */

#nav > ul
{
 height: 3em;
-moz-transition: opacity .5s ease .1s;
-webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease .1s;
-o-transition: opacity .5s ease .1s;
-ms-transition: opacity .5s ease .1s;
transition: opacity .5s ease .1s;

}
#nav > ul > li
    {
height: 100%;
float: left;
-webkit-transition: all .5s linear; 
-moz-transition: all .5s linear; 
transition: all .5s linear; 
    }

/* second level */

#nav li ul
{
    display: none;
    opacity: 0; 
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;

/* TRY */
-moz-transition: opacity .5s ease .1s;
-webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease .1s;
-o-transition: opacity .5s ease .1s;
-ms-transition: opacity .5s ease .1s;
transition: opacity .5s ease .1s;
background: #ffffff;
}
#nav li:hover ul
    {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1; 

/* TRY */
-webkit-transition: all .5s linear; 
-moz-transition: all .5s linear; 
transition: all .5s linear; 
text-decoration:none;   
/* TRY */
-moz-transition: height .5s ease .1s;
-webkit-transition: height .5s ease .1s;
-o-transition: height .5s ease .1s;
-ms-transition: height .5s ease .1s;
transition: height .5s ease .1s;
    }

/* ADDED BY ME */
#nav li ul a {
margin: 0 0 0 0;
letter-spacing: 2px;
width: 120px;
text-align:left;
text-transform:uppercase;

}


@media only screen and ( max-width: 40em ) /* 640 */
    {
        html
        {
            font-size: 75%; /* 12 */
        }

        #nav
        {
            position: relative;
            top: auto;
            left: auto;
        }
            #nav > a
            {
                width: 3.125em; /* 50 */
                height: 3.125em; /* 50 */
                text-align: left;
                text-indent: -9999px;
                background-color: #000000;
                position: relative;
            }
                #nav > a:before,
                #nav > a:after
                {
                    position: absolute;
                    border: solid 2px #FFF;
                    top: 35%;
                    left: 25%;
                    right: 25%;
                    content: '';
                }
                #nav > a:after
                {
                    top: 60%;
                }

            #nav:not( :target ) > a:first-of-type,
            #nav:target > a:last-of-type
            {
                display: block;
            }


        /* first level */

        #nav > ul
        {
            height: auto;
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
        }
            #nav:target > ul
            {
                display: block;

            }
            #nav > ul > li
            {
                width: 40%;
                float: none;
            }

                #nav > ul > li > a
                {
                    height: auto;
                    text-align: left;
                        background-color: #FFF;

                }
                    #nav > ul > li:not( :last-child ) > a
                    {
                        border-right: none;
                                                    border-top: none;
                        border-bottom: none;   


                    }


            /* second level */

            #nav li ul
            {
                position: static;

            }

#nav li ul a {
margin: 0 0 0 0;
letter-spacing: 2px;
background-color: #FFF;
text-align:left;
text-transform:uppercase;
width: 20em;

}
    }
```

Comment: can you share HTML as well. Looks like your the css which you have added under .tabs for li needs to be add for nav but share the html as well

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're having is that your menu headers (Asia, Pacific, etc) are links (`<a>` tags). On a desktop browser you can hover your mouse on these links and that triggers via the `aria-haspopup` to show the sub menu beneath that.

On a mobile device you cannot hover and instead have to click, but when you click the `<a>` tag receives that and processes it as you trying to visit the URL. You need to use javascript to determine whether a click should trigger the dropdown menu (like you want on mobile) or go to the root category (like you want on desktop).

Comment: Actually, I have been reading about aria-haspopup. If you check [my blog](http://www.dontplayahate.com) in a mobile device (e.g. iPhone 6Plus) and put the screen in landscape, the aria-haspopup behavior makes the menu work as expected (i.e. in mobile when you tap the menu opens but does NOT go to the category on top). The problem ONLY appears when the mobile screen (hamburger) becomes narrowers and the hamburger kicks in...